# Using autotools ./configure in a shared source tree

Tags: file-permissions, autotools

I am working on building a large and complex source-tree based on autotools ./configure on a shared supercomputer (named, OpenModelica https://github.com/OpenModelica/OpenModelica/blob/master/README.md). Because it is a large build, we would like to log in and use the same source tree while we are working through the compilation issues, even though we have different user accounts (but the 'chgrp' group ownership is a group that we are both members of).

When running ./configure, we have various problems, for example ./configure tries and fails to change the ownership of the file 'config.guess'. And there are various other files that are created with ownership settings that seem to prevent shared use of the source code tree.

I feel like there should be some simple 'chmod' or 'chown' setting of ownership for this source tree that would overcome this problem, but I haven't been able to figure it out. Any suggestions?

To clarify, we also want to share the build output files, not just the source code. We want to avoid having to duplicate the files (limited storage quota) or repeat the build (slow, tedious). Also, we do not have the liberty to create additional accounts on this system, or sharing a single account at least not without making a 'special request'.

Comment: Even though building an Autotools project is the context for this question, it is not framed as being *about* the autotools, or even programming, at all.  It would be on-topic over at [Unix & Linux SE](https://unix.stackexchange.com/) or at [Super User SE](https://superuser.com/).

Comment: In any case, I think there are numerous issues with your plan, but some of the specific ones you mention would be eased by a two-pronged approach: (1) ensure that all users sharing access to the source tree have the same *primary* group, and assign group ownership of the whole source tree to that group, and (2) ensure that all users sharing access have a default `umask` setting of 007 or maybe 002, and that all files and directories in the source tree are group-writable.

Comment: Thanks, John Bollinger -- we'll take a look at the umask and 'primary group' settings and see if we missed something there.

Comment: You're welcome.  And since it sounds like I may have lost you with "primary group", I note that although a user can be a member of many groups, exactly one of them is their primary group.  This matters to you because when a user creates a new file, it is normally their primary group that is assigned as the file's owning group.  The owner of the host directory does not factor in.  This will cause trouble in your scenario if those sharing the source tree have different primary groups.